# How do I update a DataGrid after it has already been loaded?

Tags: c#, datagrid

[image]

The above shows my DataGrid.dataGrid_Loaded() method creating a couple of "records" and adding them to a list that my DataGrid uses a its "ItemsSource"

On line 156 I have another record commented out (which is after the grid.ItemsSource was set). If I add that line back in, my code breaks. There must be a way to update my DataGrid with new data, but how?

Thank you for your help!

When I uncomment line 156, I get:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.

See the inner exception for more information.

Comment: Define and explain `my code breaks`.  What problem are we trying to solve?

Comment: why don't you move the line where you are adding up one prior to setting the ItemsSource or you can set the grid.ItemsSource = null then uncomment the line and then adde the grid.ItemSource = records after that..

Comment: @MethodMan The problem I'm having is that I cannot update the ItemsSource without the app crashing. I have the line where it is as an example, eventually my DataGrid will be updated with data received over sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear `ItemsSource` before changing it:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;

// some code

dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
items.Add("c");
dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;

// dataGrid contains: "a", "b", "c"
```

You may want to use `ObservableCollection<T>` and use binding in your XAML - items will update automatically.